# Hidden/Sliding Side Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make a nav bar that hides upon scrolling down and then only reveals its self when it is hovered over, any help would be appreciated.

Tried using some JavaScript but to no success so I've just left that code out.

Relatively new and just trying to figure some things out, sorry if my post isn't very clear or not in the right formatting.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#mySidenav a {
  position:fixed;
  right: -10px;
  transition: 0.7s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0px 5px;
  opacity: .5;
}


#mySidenav a:hover {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Web Site CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
 
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">Exhibitions</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Past Work</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Social Info</a>
</div>
 
<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>Looking to hide the nav bar when scrolled down and if the page isn't at the top</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down to understand what I'm meaning</p>
  <p>Also looking to make it slide out when hovered over </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
 
 <script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("about").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("blog").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("projects").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("contact").style.right = "-10px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("about").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("blog").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("projects").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("contact").style.right = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
 </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `!important` `right` property  on `#mySidenav a:hover`

```
#mySidenav a:hover {
  right: 0 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/w9u5bfL7/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Just Try this :**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#mySidenav a {
  position:fixed;
  right: -10px;
  transition: 0.7s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0px 5px;
  opacity: .5;
}


#mySidenav a:hover {
right: 0 !important;
opacity: 1;
   }

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Web Site CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
 
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">Exhibitions</a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">Past Work</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Social Info</a>
</div>
 
<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>Looking to hide the nav bar when scrolled down and if the page isn't at the top</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down to understand what I'm meaning</p>
  <p>Also looking to make it slide out when hovered over </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
 
 <script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("about").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("blog").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("projects").style.right = "-10px";
 document.getElementById("contact").style.right = "-10px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("about").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("blog").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("projects").style.right = "-100px";
 document.getElementById("contact").style.right = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
 </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**What changes made by me in your code?**

I only use important property to solve your problem

> **I replace this :**   `right: 0;`    **To this :**   `right: 0 !important;`.

Hope this will help you,
Thank you.